# Memory profiling

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dottrace

I'm using dotTrace Memory to trying to find out why an application leaks memory.

The problem is that the memory usage shown in the snapshot doesn't get anywhere near the memory which is used (private working set in perfmon).

Have I configured dotTrace incorrectly or does it mean that the extra memory is from unmanaged resources that dotTrace can't track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might be caused by several reasons:

- dotTrace Memory doesn't work with native memory, it supports only managed memory profiling,
- Memory used by assemblies is not tracked,
- GC reclaims memory, but it's not logged as free.

Comment: ehh, isn't memory used by referenced assemblies tracked? Why not?

Comment: In fact only memory used by allocated managed objects is tracked.

Comment: Does that mean that objects created in referenced .NET assemblies are being tracked?

Comment: Yes, these objects are tracked.